# Can Notification Center be made black/dark in macOS Sierra beta?

Tags: mac, beta-seed-program, macos

How do you get Notification Center to be dark/black in macOS Sierra beta? I had it that way in OS X El Capitan but cannot find how to do it in new beta.

Comment: To make your notification center dark again, use the following shortcut:

ctrl + option + cmd + 8

Answer (score 3):

Since the macOS Sierra update (Including Betas) the Notification Panel no longer uses the Dark Mode option, therefore it is permanently in light mode. This is an intended feature.

When Dark Mode is enabled on macOS Mojave or later, it will appear dark:

[image: Dark mode in Notification Center]

Answer (score 1):

Apple haven't made the notification center darkmodus yet after launching macOS Sierra. This withholds some users to update.

Comment: I don't think the statement "this withholds (sic) some users to update" is a true statement and it's definitely one you can't prove.  It's true there is no 'dark mode' for notifications but that's probably where your answer should end.

Comment: Isn't it quite easy to prove? http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/notification-center-in-sierra-is-white-in-dark-mode.2000021/

Answer (score -3):

Do Control+Command+Option+8. It usually inverts the colors.

Comment: That's the keyboard shortcut to invert ALL screen colors, not to change Notification Center only.

Comment: above comment is correct. I am not looking to invert all colors.